# Microsoft Excel Copy one row to another worksheet if cell contains specific data

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I have never written a macro in excel before. I am trying to organize my PTAs spirit wear orders for ease of placing the order. I have entered all orders into a master worksheet titled "spirit wear". I have separate tabs created for each size we are selling (22 different options). I would like the macro to search the master worksheet and copy the rows that correspond to the correct size.

For example, I would like all of the orders for L GC (large grey child) to be copied to a tab title L GC.

If anyone can help me, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Typically users here want to see what you've tried to solve your problem, just so it's clear that you aren't asking "Hey, will someone do my work for me?" If you add a little detail showing what you've tried or what ideas you have but don't know how to implement, you're more likely to get upvotes and answers.

Comment: @nixda Great! Who's owning the copyrights to this comment?

Comment: @boboes Feel free to reuse this text. I only quoted someone else. A tip: I saved it under my SU account » edit » about me. A leading `<` and closing `>` will hide the text in normal view